# Rspec - problems with switching from plugins to gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

When dropping the use of rspec and rspec-rails plugins and switching to the gem versions instead, is there anything extra I have to change in spec_helper.rb or something to make the specs in my app see the change?

I can no longer get my specs to run successfully anymore after deleting the plugins and installing the gems (1.1.8).

More specifically, this is what I did:

1. delete previously-installed rspec and rspec-rails plugins from vendors dir
2. sudo installed both rspec and rspec-rails gems (1.1.8 were the latest as of this writing)

When running script/autospec, I get this message:

> /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:578:in `report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: hoe(1.5.0 not >= 1.7.0) (Gem::LoadError)
>       from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:134:in`activate'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:158:in `activate'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:157:in`each'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:157:in `activate'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in `require'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in`new_constants_in'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in `require'
>       from /Volumes/tangoflash/code/tangoflash/spec/spec_helper.rb:5
>       from spec/helpers/sessions_helper_spec.rb:1:in`require'
>       from spec/helpers/sessions_helper_spec.rb:1

When attempting to run a single rspec example via textmate, I get:

> /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:578:in `report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: hoe(1.5.0 not >= 1.7.0) (Gem::LoadError) from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:134:in`activate' from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:158:in `activate' from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:157:in`each' from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:157:in `activate' from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require' from /Users/allanlibunao/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/RSpec.tmbundle/Support/lib/spec/mate.rb:14 from /tmp/temp_textmate.KQTYKh:3:in `require' from /tmp/temp_textmate.KQTYKh:3

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your error message it looks like you do not have a recent version of the `hoe` gem installed. Try doing a `gem install hoe --version '> 1.7.0` and see if it helps. It may be that when you installed the `rspec` and `rspec-rails` gems you did not get the dependencies as well and there may be other dependent gems missing.

Comment: Yes! That worked!

The error messages are gone and my specs are running fine again.  I'm glad that the fix was a gem dependency and not something more complicated.

Thanks again!

Comment: FYI, the "error: hoe(1.5.0 not >= 1.7.0)" is the giveaway. In saying that, it doesn't make any sense unless you already knew that 'hoe' is another gem which gets used by rake and rspec :-)